# Does building a POJO outside of the mono method cause blocking behaviour?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Currently I have a method which looks like this:

```
public Mono<Either<CommunicationException, AuthenticateResponse>> authenticate(String provider, String subject, String redirectUri) {
    final var req = AuthenticationRequest.builder().withAuthenticationProvider(provider).withRedirectUri(redirectUri).withSubject(subject).build();
        return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(authenticationClient.authenticate(req))
                        .map(this::mapAuthenticateResponse)
                        .map(Either::<CommunicationException, AuthenticateResponse>right))
                .doOnError(err -> LOGGER.error("Failed to authenticate", err))
                .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just(new CommunicationException(e.getMessage())).map(Either::left));
}
```

I am a bit unsure how it with reactive chains, will this be non-blocking even though the request is built outside of the Mono.defer() method?

I am not sure how I would go about debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

If your `AuthenticationRequest` builder is a simple POJO builder without any database calls or synchronized methods, etc, it will not cause any blocking.

Usually, it's recommended to move such a code into the chain. In the Reactor, nothing happens until you subscribe, but if you move your code outside of a chain, it can be executed before subscribing (as part of the chain assembling phase).

For example, this code prints "hello world" even if there is no subscription on Reactor chain:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getData();
}

public static Mono<String> getData() {
    var req = new MyRequest(1);
    System.out.println("hello world");
    return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(req))
        .map(Object::toString);
}
```

But this code prints nothing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getData();
}

public static Mono<String> getData() {
    return Mono.defer(() -> {
            var req = new MyRequest(1);
            System.out.println("hello world");
            return Mono.just(req);
        })
        .map(Object::toString);
}
```

See more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76275996/6933090

But actually, in your case, nothing wrong should happen if you move it outside of `Mono.defer` (as in your example), but it's anyway better to move it into a chain like this:

```java
Mono.fromCallable(() -> AuthenticationRequest.builder()
        .withAuthenticationProvider(provider)
        .withRedirectUri(redirectUri)
        .withSubject(subject)
        .build())
    .map(req -> authenticationClient.authenticate(req))
    .map(this::mapAuthenticateResponse)
```